# Change "Send to" or "Rotate counterclockwise" accelerator key in Win 7 Explorer context menu

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, send-to, accelerator

In my English Windows 7's windows explorer, I can right-click a file and press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the *Send to* submenu, unless it's an image file, in which case it toggles between *Send to* and *Rotate counterclockwise*, and I need to press <kbd>N</kbd> twice, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the *Send to* submenu.

Is there a way e.g. by editing the registry but not hacking Windows's binaries to change either accelerator key so that they don't clash?

Alternatively, is there another way to open the *Send to* submenu with one keypress, without installing extra software e.g. AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily disable the rotation functions if you do not need them (honestly, it's better to use a dedicated image editor for such operations, esp. one that is capable of lossless JPEG transforms and which allows you to decide what to do while rotating images with partial MCUs). Just download [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html), run it, search for **Windows Photo Viewer Image Verbs** and disable the context menu entry.

Now unless something else decides to steal <kbd>N</kbd>, you'll be free to open *Send to* via a single keypress.

Comment: Thanks, Karan. It works, and has given me new opportunities to customise my context menus, though it involves installing extra software. I'll mark it as the correct answer if noone else has any answers.

Comment: @Gnubie: No install required, all NirSoft utils are portable.

Comment: For anyone that prefers to use regedit, you can either delete `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{FFE2A43C-56B9-4bf5-9A79-CC6D4285608A}` to get rid of all context menu items or modify the data to remove specific items.

Comment: On my system ShellExView doesn't work, even if ownership is given to Administrators on `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{FFE2A43C-56B9-4bf5-9A79-CC6D4285608A}`

Comment: @Jeff: Did you try the latest version i.e. 1.90? Did you try running the program as admin? If it still fails perhaps Process Monitor can tell you why.

Comment: Yes to both questions; v1.90 of ShellExView and run as Admin. The user `TrustedInstaller` owned the key. I ended up going full nuclear and renamed PhotoViewer.dll. I hated to do it, but...

Comment: @Jeff: Did you try manually deleting or renaming the registry key?

Comment: Yes, I took ownership and deleted the key. First I tried manually removing the two "rotate" options. Strangely neither of these worked, which tells me something else is going on with my system - but what in the world could it be? Win7 SP1.

Comment: I fixed it with ShellExView! I had "Show 32-bit Shell Extensions" checked under the Options menu. I forgot to turn it off after I used it last. Unchecked the option, disabled `Windows Photo Viewer Image Verbs`, rebooted (required) and VIOLA! Nuking my PhotoViewer.dll was driving me mad, so I had to figure it out.